# How to find my OpenId of Wechat personal account which is following a Wechat Service Account

Tags: wechat, wechat-miniprogram

OpenId is an id of a Wechat personal account when it is following a Wechat Service Account. And the OpenIds are different for the same Wechat personal account in different Wechat Service Accounts.

So I want to find out OpenId of single account only and not the list of all the OpenIds which are following that WeChat service account.

Does anyone know how to get it?

I have to use it to send a message in https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/message/template/send

Comment: This is not a question for StackOverflow as much as to support channel for the specific software in question. You might want to ask it in the right channel.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user info via their UnionID first,(https://developers.weixin.qq.com/doc/offiaccount/en/User_Management/Get_users_basic_information_UnionID.html#UinonId) and then use the OpenID relevant to the current Official Account to send the Templated Message.

This way, your applications just need to track the UnionID, and get the user info on the fly, when needed (can be cached to avoid too many API calls etc).

Comment: Can you please tell how can I get Union id and what is the api to get the information from that.

Comment: @bhatmoder it's right in the page linked in the answer above. https://api.weixin.qq.com/cgi-bin/user/info?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&openid=OPENID&lang=zh_CN
See the actual documantation page for details regarding parameters and returned data.

Answer (score 0):

1.Registing your service account with your email.

2.Getting your appid and appsecret.The appsecret must be saved after gained.

3.Setting the white doname in wechat service account managesites.When you are setting the doname, wechat will make you download a file and put it in your remote server where the doname sets.It will ensure the setting is from you and you can Scan code with your wxchat client.

4.Editing the miniprogram code. Use the method "wx.login()".you can get the jscode in the callback of "wx.login()" send it to your remote server.

5.Editing the remote server code.Send "get" request to get openid with your appid ,appsecret,the jscode from client.
https://api.weixin.qq.com/sns/jscode2session?appid=APPID&secret=SECRET&js_code=JSCODE&grant_type=authorization_code